# itextsharp using unsupported API

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, itext, windows-8.1, windows-store

I created Windows 8 app with iTextsharp library added by nuget. I implemented changes, tested app, everything was ok but when I run 'Windows App Certification Kit' I'm getting a lot of errors that many of API uses by iTextsharp is unsupported in this type of app. 
For example:

```
API System.ICloneable in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. itextsharp.dll calls this API.

API System.IO.FileSystemInfo in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. itextsharp.dll calls this API.

API System.IO.FileInfo in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. itextsharp.dll calls this API.

API System.Drawing.Color in SYSTEM.DRAWING, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B03F5F7F11D50A3A is not supported for this application type. itextsharp.dll calls this API.
```

Has anyone ever published windows app with iTextsharp on Microsoft store?

Comment: The official iTextSharp binaries (I can't speak for what's on NuGet) have a DLL called `itextsharp-dll-core-wo_Drawing` that, based solely upon the name sounds like it doesn't have the `System.Drawing` namespace referenced. Its possible that other items have been removed, too, so I'd look there first. Otherwise, if you're selling something on the store then that would be a good use of your paid support contract. Your third option would be to just download the source and remove those instance, shouldn't take too long, probably.

Comment: I dont know of any free pdf libraries for windows store apps.  Syncfusion has a library that is not expensive if you qualify for there hobbyist offer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried 'wo_Drawing' but there is still unsupported API. I downloaded code from sourceforge and started rewrite library.